# How to install keytar behind corporate registry?

Tags: node.js, npm, yarnpkg

I'm tryingto install keytar on my windows64 machine behind corporate registry.

But I got this error:

```
λ npm i keytar

> keytar@7.7.0 install C:\m\node_modules\keytar
> prebuild-install || npm run build

prebuild-install WARN install getaddrinfo EAI_AGAIN github.com

> keytar@7.7.0 build C:\m\node_modules\keytar
> node-gyp rebuild


C:\m\node_modules\keytar>if not defined npm_config_node_gyp (node "C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\npm-lifecycle\node-gyp-bin\\..\..\node_modules\node-gyp\bin\node-gyp.js" rebuild )  else (node "C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\node-gyp\bin\node-gyp.js" rebuild )
gyp WARN install got an error, rolling back install
gyp ERR! configure error
gyp ERR! stack Error: getaddrinfo EAI_AGAIN nodejs.org
gyp ERR! stack     at GetAddrInfoReqWrap.onlookup [as oncomplete] (dns.js:67:26)
gyp ERR! System Windows_NT 10.0.17763
gyp ERR! command "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\node_modules\\node-gyp\\bin\\node-gyp.js" "rebuild"
gyp ERR! cwd C:\m\node_modules\keytar
gyp ERR! node -v v14.17.0
gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v5.1.0
gyp ERR! not ok
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! keytar@7.7.0 build: `node-gyp rebuild`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the keytar@7.7.0 build script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
npm WARN Local package.json exists, but node_modules missing, did you mean to install?
```

Seems that keytar wants access to nodejs.org, but my organization doesn't allow me to do it.

The problem is I have some library (don't know which) that uses keytar as dependency and try to download and install.

Is there a way to make it work anyway?